# Using two aggregate functions with HAVING clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, hana

I have below table -

```
MOBILE    AMOUNT
-----------------
M1          10
M1          20 
M1          30
M2          40   
M2          10
M3          30
```

I want to find count of distinct mobiles having total amount greater than 40.

So I have written query with inner query as -

```
select count(mobile)
from
(
select mobile,sum(amount)
from TAB
group by mobile
having sum(amount) >40
)
```

Is there a way to write this with plain query i.e. without inner query.

Output needed (as only M1 and M2 have sum(amount) >40)-

```
CNT
---
2
```

Comment: Are you using Oracle or SAP HANA? Those are two very different database products

Comment: We are using both databases.

Comment: I can't think of a way of doing this without a subquery.  And your current query looks fine to me.

Comment: yes I just want count of distinct mobiles.

Comment: What's wrong with the query you have? Why can't you use it?

Comment: We are building a functionality where we want to find mobile/customers depending on various combinations. Rest all combinations are plain filters which can be handled in 'WHERE ...' clause. We want to store only 'WHERE...' clause as rest of the query remains same. Only in case of aggregated filters my query changes to inner query.

Comment: @STDMP - NO it does not give correct output

Comment: The only way I can think of is to create a VIEW for the inner query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nested query you provided in your example is the correct one. You are asking for an aggregation on a higher level than the `SUM(amount)`; you are asking for the number of resulting groups.

In your comment, you mentioned that the main concern is that the structure of the SQL statement changes when you include aggregation. That's how the SQL language handles different query semantics.
Just changing `WHERE` clauses will only allow for swapping filter conditions.

If you want to enable filtering on aggregated characteristics, then you have to have the multi-level-approach with SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
SQL> with test (mobile, amount) as
  2  (select 'm1', 10 from dual union
  3   select 'm1', 20 from dual union
  4   select 'm1', 30 from dual union
  5   select 'm2', 40 from dual union
  6   select 'm2', 10 from dual union
  7   select 'm3', 30 from dual
  8  )
  9  select sum(count(distinct mobile)) cnt
 10  from test
 11  group by mobile
 12  having sum(amount) > 40;

       CNT
----------
         2

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot this works in ORACLE :)...but sadly i got below error in SAP HANA.-SAP DBTech JDBC: [279]: group function is nested: line 1 col 12 (at pos 11)

Comment: Sorry, I don't use SAP HANA & have no idea what you should or might do.